# preposition choice: vary from...to... or vary between...and

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

I'm wondering whether "vary from ... to ..." or "vary between ... and ..." are interchangeable in the following. Both seem to describe the range within which something can vary.

> 1. The value of John's entire collection varies **from** $500 **to** $1,000.
> 2. The value of John's entire collection varies **between** $500 **and** $1,000.
> 3. The monthly salaries of Peter's employees vary **from** US$2,500 **to** US$3,000.
> 4. Sam’s monthly salary varies **between** US$3,000 **and** US$4,000.

I'd appreciate your help

Answer (score -1):

Do you know what

> **between**

means. In your usage they are the same.

> The value of John's collection varies from $500 to $1,000, it is somewhere in **between**.